# Print rectangle with Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to print rectangle like below using Ruby:

```
* = = = *
* = = = *
* * * * *
* = = = *
* = = = *
```

in this case, length of row and column are same and must odd.

Example:

r = rectangle(5)

should print :

```
* = = = *
* = = = *
* * * * *
* = = = *
* = = = *
```

and if :

r = rectangle(7)

should print:

```
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How `rectangle(3)` looks?

Comment: Do you know how to print characters? Do you know how to write a loop? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Thank all, SOLVED . Just use modulo work for me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by creating the two lines: (there are plenty of ways to achieve this)

```
size = 7

a = Array.new(size, '*').fill('=', 1..-2).join(' ') #=> "* = = = = = *"
b = Array.new(size, '*').join(' ')                  #=> "* * * * * * *"
```

Then I'd define a repeating pattern:

```
pattern = [a, a, b].cycle
```

Finally, I'd print the pattern *size* times:

```
puts pattern.take(size)
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
```

Comment: Cycle + take, I like that.

Comment: All answers here are great, but this answer simply and elegant, ruby ways. I mark this answer as the answer for my question Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVE BY ME] :D

```
def square(n)
  begin
    if n.odd?
      1.upto(n) do | row |
        if row % 3 != 0
          puts "#{'*'} #{'= ' * (n - 2)}#{'*'}"
        else
          puts "#{'* ' * n}"
        end
      end
    else
      puts 'Must odd number!'
    end
  rescue
    puts 'Must integer number!'
  end
end
```

`square(5)`
Output:

```
* = = = *
* = = = *
* * * * *
* = = = *
* = = = *
```

`square(7)`
Output:

```
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
* = = = = = *
* * * * * * *
* = = = = = *
```

`square(8)`
Output:

`Must odd number!`

`square(8.5)`
Output:

`Must integer number!`

`square('blabla')`
Output:

`Must integer number!`

Comment: Your code actually prints `#` instead of `=` and the spaces are missing.

Comment: What `square('blabla')` will return? ;)

Comment: @spn, now you have extra whitespace in the end of every third line.

Comment: Consider using guard clauses for argument checking. Something like `raise TypeError unless n.is_a? Integer` as the method's first line.

Comment: `square(1)` returns `Must integer number!` it's not good idea.

Comment: Also try for example `square(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def rectangle(n)
  puts("-----------------For #{n}--------------------")
  if n % 2 == 1
    for i in (1..n)
      for j in (1..n)
        if j == 1 || j == n || 0 == i % 3
          print "* "
        else
          print "= "
        end
      end
      print("\n")
    end
  end
end

rectangle(3)
rectangle(5)
rectangle(7)
rectangle(9)
rectangle(11)

-----------------For 3--------------------
* = * 
* = * 
* * * 

-----------------For 5--------------------
* = = = * 
* = = = * 
* * * * * 
* = = = * 
* = = = * 

-----------------For 7--------------------
* = = = = = * 
* = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * 
* = = = = = * 
* = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * 
* = = = = = * 

-----------------For 9--------------------
* = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * 

-----------------For 11--------------------
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * * * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * * * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* * * * * * * * * * * 
* = = = = = = = = = * 
* = = = = = = = = = *
```

Comment: Thanks. Will be my reference

Comment: `print "* "` results in a stray space at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun modify @spn answer

```
def rectangle(count)
  return 'Must odd number more than 1' unless count.is_a?(Integer) && count.odd? && count > 1
  Array.new(count) { |index| (index + 1) % 3 == 0 ?
                               "#{'* ' * count}".chomp(" ") :
                               "#{'*'} #{'= ' * (count - 2)}#{'*'}" }.join("\n")
end
```

And now

```
puts rectangle(2) # will print Must odd number more than 1
puts rectangle("asdf") # will print Must odd number more than 1
```

```
puts rectangle(9) # will print:
```

```
* = = = = = = = *
* = = = = = = = *
* * * * * * * * *
* = = = = = = = *
* = = = = = = = *
* * * * * * * * *
* = = = = = = = *
* = = = = = = = *
* * * * * * * * *
```

It's better to avoid `puts` in the methods. So you can use them again in web, telegrambots, etc. Also it's not good idea to duplicate Ruby exceptions by your own (but the same) messages.

Comment: `unless count.is_a?(Integer) && count.odd?` might be easier to read. And instead of overwriting the `nil` values in the array, you can pass a block to `Array.new` to specify the elements directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first define a method to construct the two types of lines.

```
def make_line(n, mid_char)
  ['*', *[mid_char]*(n-2), '*'].join(' ')
end

make_line(5, '*') #=> "* * * * *" 
make_line(5, '#') #=> "* # # # *"
```

Now create a method to draw the lines in the desired pattern. The `i`th line (base zero) is comprised of stars and spaces only if `(i+1) % 3` equals zero; else it is the line containing pound signs as well.

```
def draw(n)
  all_stars = make_line(n, '*')
  two_stars = make_line(n, '#')  
  n.times { |i| puts ((i+1) % 3).zero? ? all_stars : two_stars }
end
```

```
draw 5
* # # # *
* # # # *
* * * * *
* # # # *
* # # # *
draw 6
* # # # # *
* # # # # *
* * * * * *
* # # # # *
* # # # # *
* * * * * *
draw 7
* # # # # # *
* # # # # # *
* * * * * * *
* # # # # # *
* # # # # # *
* * * * * * *
* # # # # # *
```